# using Expandable listview as radio button

Tags: android, listview, radio-group

I have used expandable list view in my application. Now what I want to do is user to show only one items child at a time.... 
If user clicks on first item then the view should be..

item 1:

Radio button 1

Radio button 2

item 2:

now if after clicking first item user clicks on second then it should show..

item 1:

item 2:

Radio button 1

Radio button 2

how to achieve that?

my getChildView method of adapter is..

```
 @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
    }
    RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbtn1);
    RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbtn2);



    return convertView;
}
```

`child_item` contains a radio group here, and `getGroupView` method is..

```
 @Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Group group = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
    tv.setText(group.getName());
    return convertView;
}
```

The problem here is, after clicking first if I click second, then both first and second are in checked state and shows content instead of only second items content..
I have set `CHOICE_MODE` to Single Choice.. but its not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even i don't know any inbuilt functions but you can try this code.

```
 YourexpandableList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
        int previousGroup = -1;

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        if(groupPosition != previousGroup)
            YourexpandableList.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
        previousGroup = groupPosition;
    }
});
```